# Using dependency injection on a class with a list<interface<T>> property where T is unknown

Tags: c#, generics, orm, fluent-nhibernate

Please consider the following scenario...

I have objects to define different types of products and the properties required to describe that product (e.g. a television will have different attributes to a perfume etc).

As such, I have the concept of a `ProductType` which has a `List<>` property with elements for the different fields (`AttributeField<T>`).

`AttributeField<T>` has a `List<>` property for the different values (`AttributeValue<T>`).

A product then has a `ProductType` to define the available fields (`AttributeField<T>`) and a `List<AttributeValue<?>>` for the values for this specific product.

I am trying to implement this concept in C#. I have the structure defined for the interfaces and objects but am struggling to map the objects using Fluent NHibernate, presumably because the `ProductType` is not a generic class but has a generic property (`List<AttributeField<T>>` where T can be anything).

Interfaces > IProductType

```
public interface IProductType
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<IAttributeField> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

Interfaces > IAttributeField / IAttributeField

```
public interface IAttributeField
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    IProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}

public interface IAttributeField<T> : IAttributeField
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<IAttributeValue<T>> Values { get; set; }
    IProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

Interfaces > IAttributeValue

```
public interface IAttributeValue<T>
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    T Value { get; set; }
    IAttributeField<T> Field { get; set; }
}
```

Classes > ProductType

```
public class ProductType : IProductType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<IAttributeField> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

Classes > AttributeField

```
public class AttributeField<T> : IAttributeField<T>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<IAttributeValue<T>> Values { get; set; }
    public IProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

Classes > AttributeValue

```
public class AttributeValue<T> : IAttributeValue<T>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public IAttributeField<T> Field { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Fluent NHibernate for ORM with a SQL 2008 database and have the following mapping classes:

Classes > ProductTypeMapping

```
public class ProductTypeMapping : ClassMap<IProductType>
{
    public ProductTypeMapping()
    {
        Not.LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidNative();
        Map(x => x.Name).Length(50).Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Fields).CollectionType<IAttributeField>();
    }
}
```

Classes > AttributeFieldMapping

```
public class GenericAttributeFieldMapping : ClassMap<IAttributeField>
{
    public GenericAttributeFieldMapping()
    {
        Not.LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name).Length(50).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.ProductType).Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class AttributeFieldMapping<T> : ClassMap<IAttributeField<T>>
{
    public AttributeFieldMapping()
    {
        Not.LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidNative();
        Map(x => x.Name).Length(50).Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Values).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
        References(x => x.ProductType).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Classes > AttributeValueMapping

```
public class AttributeValueMapping<T> : ClassMap<IAttributeValue<T>>
{
    public AttributeValueMapping()
    {
        Not.LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidNative();
        Map(x => x.Value).CustomType<T>();
        References(x => x.Field).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

When I try to unit test the above with a `new PersitenceSpecification<ProductType>` I get the following error:

**Unit Test Adapter threw exception: 
Type is not resolved for member 'FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException,FluentNHibernate, Version=1.3.0.733, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8aa435e3cb308880'..**

When debugging further I get the following exception message:

**No persister for: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Models.Interfaces.IAttributeField, Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]**

Presumably this is because I cannot use generic types for mapping and need to provide mapping for each generic type to map against.

How can I have the structure detailed above work with dependency injection and ORM without having to explicitly provide mapping for each generic type OR what changes can be made to my approach to work with ORM whilst still providing the flexibility to have models with different attributes (fields and values)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluent NHibernate is an Object Relation Mapper and persistence solution. It's not a dependency injection container.

It would be much easier to give a concrete answer with visibility of the database schema. However I understand this may not be practical.

It sounds to me like you are trying to create your application objects using Fluent NHibernate rather than just relying on it for persistence. This will probably result in some very complicated mapping as part of the ORM which may result in a lot of mapping classes. As stated here, you need a mapping class for each concrete type in your generics: [Map generic EntityBase<TEntity> class with FluentNHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631384/map-generic-entitybasetentity-class-with-fluentnhibernate) So it your example I think you will need one for every `IAttributeField<T>` and every `IAttributeValue<T>`

I would try and simplify the mapping classes as much as possible to match your data model and use a service layer with some factories or AutoMapper to construct your application objects. Separating your persisted entities from the application is not always advised (as it can add unnecessary layers and complexity - Macaroni code) but in a situation like this it seems like it might be necessary.

As I say, start at the data model and work outwards is best here and make sure you understand that Fluent NHibernate is just an ORM with many powerful features